# x11vnc [properties] accept connections at startup

Tags: startup, vnc

I have installed the x11vnc on my Tinker Board but at startup I can't connect to it: "Connection refused by Host". I have to log in and go to properties and allow "accept connections" in order to connect via vnc.

How can I connect to it without first having to activate "accept connections" or what do I have to do so x11vnc accepts connections at startup?

Answer (score 0):

Check which firewall is active on the Tinker board and disable the firewall.

The connection should go through without you having to accept connection at startup.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).